# How to add struts-layout.jar entry in pom.xml

Tags: struts, maven-3

i am trying to deploy  struts 1.3 based application using maven. 
I want to add Struts-Layout.jar entry in pom.xml.

after goggling i got this answer to add following entry in pom.xml:

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>Struts-Layout</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

But it gives this error :

```
  [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project sample: Could not resolve depe
    ndencies for project com.sample.cms:sample:war:1.1.32: Failure to find o
    rg.apache.struts:Struts-Layout:jar:1.3 in http://maven.springframework.org/exter
    nal was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until
     the update interval of spring-maven-external has elapsed or updates are forced
```

version of maven is Maven 3.0.3
    How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

See http://bug.improve-community.com/view.php?id=160. It seems that this library is not deployed on any public maven repo. You'll have to download it and add it to your own private repository.